# Xcode Developer Tools on Jailbroken iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, jailbreak, ipa

Is there a way to install the XCode developer tools on a jailbroken iPad to use with a bash app? I want to compile native apps on the iPad and run the ipa.

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode tools are never installed on iOS devices; so no.

Answer (score 0):

for compile.yes it's possible.
I compiled some tweaks as well as CLIs on my iPad before
EDIT:You'll need:
Darwin CC tools from BigBoss by CoolStar
THEOS(Can be found on Github)
Apple SDK(Download .dmg from developer center,and extract them,DMG extract tools exists for windows)